How to trigger multiple animations when the user clicks on the <a> (link)
I have this Html code and I want all the animations to be played after clicking on the link :


document.querySelector('.play').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.trans-up').style.animationPlayState = 'running';
  document.querySelector('.trans-mid').style.animationPlayState = 'running';
  document.querySelector('.trans-down').style.animationPlayState = 'running';
});
.trans-up {
  animation: trans-up-anim 1.8s forwards;
}

.trans-down {
  animation: trans-dow -anim 1.5s forwards;
}

.trans-mid {
  animation: trans-down-anim 1.3s forwards;
}

@keyframes trans-up-anim {
  0% {
    top: -100%
  }
}

@keyframes trans-down-anim {
  0% {
    bottom: -100%
  }
}
<a class="play">click on me<\a>

<div class="trans-up"></div>

<div class="trans-mid"></div>

<div class="trans-down"></div>




That will not answer your question but correct the closing a tag <\a> to 

your div are empty, there is nothing to animate

Your syntax is fine and as @Mister Jojo said you have nothing to animate. Add some text to your divs and change ex top -100% to top -100px you will see your animation

top and bottom don't have any effect on non-positioned elements. Plus, you should rather be using translate for stuff like this to begin with.

your code might not run due to the following reason

Div tag does not have height and width
2.Its important you give your div a position of relative, and also, you can add a transition to your CSS. A sample is provided below for you to use have a guide



document.querySelector('.play').addEventListener('click', function() {

      const target1 = document.querySelector('.trans-up');
      const target2 = document.querySelector('.trans-mid');
      const target3 = document.querySelector('.trans-down');     
      
      target1.classList.add('trans-up-animation');
      target2.classList.add('trans-mid-animation');
      target3.classList.add('trans-down-animation');
});
.trans-up-animation{
   position: relative;
   animation: trans-up-anim 2s forwards ease-out;
}
.trans-down-animation{
   transition: middle 2s running;
   animation : trans-down-anim 1.5s forwards;
}
.trans-mid-animation{
   transition: middle 4s running;
   animation : trans-down-anim 1.3s forwards;
}

@keyframes trans-up-anim {
/* Start left off screen */
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  /* Move to visible position within 8% of 9 seconds (less than a second). */
  8% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  } 
  /* Stay until at least 3 second mark (33% of 9s). */
  33.33% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  } 
  /* Move offscreen to the right while
     the next slide is moving in.
     Same duration as slide-in (8%), but starting at 33.33%,
     so 33.33% + 8% = 41.33%.
  */
  41.33% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  } 
  /* Stay there until the end. */
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }

}
@keyframes trans-down-anim {
   to {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
} 
<a class="play" href="#">click on me</a>

<div class="trans-up" style="width:100px; height:20px; background:red; position:relative:"></div>

<div class="trans-mid" style="width:100px; height:20px; background:black;  position:relative:"></div>

<div class="trans-down" style="width:100px; height:20px; background:blue;  position:relative:"></div>




There are mainly two issues in your code:

You have not closed the anchor tag properly, use "/" instead of "\".
Your animation divs do not contain any elements as well as height to make animation or transition work.

Fix the above issues and it will work.
